# On a differentiable extension of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function at each point of $G.$ Does there exists a differentiable function $\hat{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\hat{f}|_G= f,$ i.e, a differentiable extension of $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n?$ What about if we replace 'differentiable' by 'continuously differentiable' above? In case both answers are negative, under what conditions can I guarantee some statement like that?

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$?${}{}$

Comment: At the very least we would need it to be continuous on $\overline{G}$. Otherwise we can't even guarantee a continuous extension.

Comment: @ John Griffin note that $f$ is not defined on $\bar{G},$ rather than in its interior

Comment: @Magnusseen Of course. But there is no guarantee that a continuous function defined on an open set has a continuous extension. See David Mitra's comment.

Comment: @ John Griffin Of course. I was just pointing the fact that it is not right to say '$f$ would need to be continuous on $\bar{G}$ '. But I think you meant to say $f$ has a continuous extension.

Comment: @ John Griffin  Anyway, you could add as many conditions as you want. One could be, as you pointed, that $f$ has a continuous extension to $\bar{G}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example of $f(x)=1/x$ on the interval $(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ shows that in general, a differentiable (or continuously differentiable) function in an open set does not have an extension of the same class.

A sufficient condition for the existence of a continuously differentiable extension is that

- $f$ and $\nabla f$ have a limit at every boundary point of $G$ (so they extend continuously to $\overline{G}$); and
- The resulting extension to $\overline{G}$ satisfies the assumption of 
  [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem). Specifically, this assumption is that for all $x,y\in \overline{G}$,
  $$f(x)=f(y) + \nabla f(y)\cdot (x-y) + R(x,y)$$
  where $R$ is uniformly $o(|x-y|)$, meaning that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|R(x,y)|<\epsilon|x-y|$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.